# Quickbooks Premier Installer gives me 11 spaces to enter a 15-character license key

Tags: installation, windows-installer, quickbooks

When I run the installer for Quickbooks Premier 2014, 2016, or 2017, it asks me for the license key. I attempt to enter the license key, but each box has one fewer space than it should. In total, my license key has 15 characters, but there is only enough room for 11 characters when I type it in. As a result, there's not enough room to enter the whole license key.

Here's an illustration. I enter the numbers exactly as they're shown in notepad, but when I type them into the Quickbooks installer, it only gives me 11 characters to enter the 15-character license key.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to arcane mysteries beyond my comprehension, the Quickbooks installer does not support the NumPad. When you try to type in the license key using the NumPad, Quickbooks will give you 11 spaces in which to type the license key. However, if you type the license key using the number row keys, it will give you the full 15 spaces you need.

Comment: Weird. I've installed many versions of QB and never ran into this issue.

Comment: I repeated it on two different computers, and it worked the same each time, and applied to each version of Quickbooks.

Comment: Are you typing the dash when you enter the key?

Comment: Nope. Just the numbers. Here's an animated gif to demonstrate. I type the numbers exactly as they're shown in notepad, and it only gives me 11 spaces to enter a 15-character license key. https://i.imgur.com/gcxOS0K.gif

Comment: Yep. Before QuickBooks outsourced most of their US call centers to Manila, et al., I did support for them through Convergys. Strill has The real Deal.